# Fail to see the mistake when applying Cauchy's integral formulae

Tags: complex-analysis

> We need to find $\;f(z)$ with the property that
>   $$f''(a)=\oint_{\partial C_1(0)}{\sin^2z\over (z-a)^3}dz, \quad
>  \forall\;|z|<1$$

Could someone explain me why I cannot do it this way:
$$f''(a)={2!\over2\pi i}\oint_{\partial C_1(0)}{{2\pi i \over 2!}\sin^2z\over (z-a)^3}dz$$

From where we can easily read
$$\tag{1}f(z)=\pi i \sin^2z$$

This seems to be not true because
$$\oint_{\partial C_1(0)}{\sin^2z\over (z-a)^3}dz={2\pi i \over2!}(\sin^2a)''=(\pi i\sin 2a)'=2\pi i \cos 2a=f''(a)$$
From where we get
$$f'(a)=\int2\pi i \cos 2a\;\mathrm{d}a=\pi i \sin2a+C\\f(a)=\int\pi i \sin2a+C\;\mathrm{d}a=-\frac12\pi i\cos2a+Ca+D$$
So we got
$$\tag{2}f(z)=-\frac12\pi i\cos2z+Cz+D$$

Obviously $(2)$ contradicts $(1)$, and $(2)$ seems to be correct. Nevertheless I fail to see why the first method is wrong. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are missing is that

$$f''(a) = \oint_{\partial C_1(0)} \frac{\sin^2 z}{(z-a)^3}\,dz$$

only gives you the second and higher derivatives of $f$, you have

$$(f(z) - \pi i\sin^2 z)'' \equiv 0.$$

So the difference is a polynomial of degree $\leqslant 1$,

$$f(z) = \pi i\sin^2 z + a + bz.$$

The initial conditions yield $f(0) = a$ and $f'(0) = b$.

Note that

$$-\frac{1}{2}\cos (2z) = \frac{1}{2} (\sin^2 z - \cos^2 z) = \sin^2 z - \frac{1}{2},$$

so yours is an alternative form.

Comment: Perfect, I got it, thanks :) Haha, you have seen my question which I posted before this and deleted, because I have made some mistakes when typing the solution